# What’s the meaning of these verses?

Tags: meaning

I was listening a song titled “PAZZESKA” with my Italian exchange friends and I almost got everything but I can’t fully understand this verse:

> Dice che sono pazzeska 
>   Sarà il fascino della tedesca
>    Vuole uno spicchio della mia pesca
>    Mhm, frutta fresca
>    Cambio location, siamo alla festa (yah) 
>   Dinamite nella sua tasca (bom)
>    Quando arriva M¥SS KETA in pista 
>   Finalmente la situa inizia (ah)

I came up with this: 
He says I’m wonderful, probably it’s because I’m German,  he wants a slice of my peach, fresh fruits, I go somewhere else, we’re the party, dynamite in his pocket. When MYSS KETA is on the dance floor the (Situa) begins.

I’d like to know the meaning of  the 3rd, 4th, 6th and 8th lines.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! In my opinion, your question is hard to answer because some of these words/verses are simply nonsense.

Comment: What precisely stumped you? What is your best shot at a translation?  (see https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-questions-about-translation-requests-on-topic)

Comment: “Case Gescal” were (are) houses for workers: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gescal

Comment: @federicopoloni I updated my question

Comment: @Charo it’s not true: it’s slang, it looks like nonsense but it’s not. For example, “situa” is the short form of “situazione” and here it means that finally the party begins. Anyway, shrini, the content is very poor of meaning, it’s a little vulgar...

Comment: Full lyrics, for context: https://www.rockol.it/testi/166515163/m-ss-keta-feat-gue-pequeno-pazzeska

Comment: I removed the edit for “case Gescal”, that doesn't fit in the question. Please, ask a single question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the effort in providing a stub of translation! I'll update it, even if I admit I'm too old to be familiar with all the nuances of this youth jargon (I'm quickly approaching a "you kids get off my lawn" age).

> He says I’m wonderful, 
>   must be my Nordic charm

Not "because I'm German", but "because I look like a German and people have a thing for blondes"

> he wants a slice of my peach, yum, fresh fruit,

not-so-hidden sexual metaphor

> I go somewhere else,

"location" is one of those English words that people seem to find 'cool' and use even when there's a perfectly good alternative Italian word, to the point where it feels a bit comical. It has entered the jargon of young party-goers, mostly to mean the location of a party / event.

> we’re at the party, (yeah)

not "we're the party"

> dynamite in his pocket. (boom)

Looks like another sexual double-entendre, or a reference to party drugs --- not sure which.

> When MYSS KETA gets to the dance floor the party gets going. (ah)

"Situa" is short for situation, again youth slang --- I'm not too familiar with the exact nuance of meaning.

The jargon suggests a Northern Italian speaker to me, I'd guess someone in the Milan movida.

Not a great piece of poetry overall, just a lot of youth slang and vanilla "get wild on the dancefloor" lyrics.